# Run-Time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error on extracting webpage data

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

Hi I am trying to extract data from a website using excel VBA

but I am getting error on line `With Sheets("WTD Inputs PPR").Range("A1").QueryTable`

```
Sub WTDPPR()
    Set Rng = ActiveCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("WTD Inputs PPR").Visible = True
    Sheets("WTD Inputs PPR").Select
    Columns("A:AA").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    With Sheets("WTD Inputs PPR").Range("A1").QueryTable
     .Connection = "URL;" + Range("LinkWTDPPR").Value
     .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     Sheets("WTD Inputs PPR").Select
     Columns("A:A").Select
     Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
     Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
     Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), Array(17, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Sheets("WTD Inputs PPR").Visible = False

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Since I'm a novice at VBA, could you help me identify where the problem is occuring and any way i can resolve it?

Comment: Can you change it to: With Thisworkbook.Sheets("WTD Inputs PPR").Range("A1").QueryTable

Comment: And change the end with statement before Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Comment: Hi, I changed it but still error occured